# Azure Machine learning unable to take PDFs as input to web service

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a random forest experiment deployed on azure ML where I am trying to score documents based on the words they contain. The documents are in the form of PDFs. When I deploy this experiment as a web service it doesn't allow me to input PDFs. Is there a way to input PDFs to a web service?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of possible approaches:

- Serialize the bytes data for the PDF before calling the web service. In an Execute R/Python Script module inside your experiment, deserialize the data and extract the text from the PDF using third-party packages (e.g. pickle and pdfminer for Python).
- Provide a URI to the PDF as a web service input. Use an Execute R/Python Script module to retrieve the PDF file from that URI and extract the text using third-party packages (e.g. urllib.requests and pdfminer for Python).